# Changing sprites based on Static Values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has a way of upgrading your character. In this way you could purchase armor (Which is visualized by armor Sprites) You could buy a multiplier on coins OR you could buy damage!

But when the character purchases this damage Upgrade I want the sprites to be able to change. So my question is is it possible to change a sprite based on a static value within a script?

UpgradeMenu

So the idea is that the user buys upgrades with his currency. This causes the projectile damage to change from lets say 1 to 2. How am I able to change a sprite based on the value in the DamageOnHit statement?

```
    public void UpgradeArmor ()
    {
      Health.maxHealth += 2;
      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeSouls ()
    {
      EnemySlime.ScoreOnDeath += 1;
      EnemySkeleton.ScoreOnDeath += 1;
      UpdateValues();
    }

    public void UpgradeDamage ()
    {
      Projectile.DamageOnHit += 1;
      UpdateValues();
    }
```

Comment: Yes. Change the sprite in the function where you update the value of your static variable. In `UpgradeDamage()`, you can call a new function `UpdateSprite()` that looks at the value of you static variable and change the sprite accordingly.

Comment: make `UpdateValues` an event and subscribe handlers from scripts that control sprites